# Test for a program I'm programming

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing, complexity-theory

Hay!

I would like to create a test that can find the complexity (time & space) of the program.
function by function...
I thought of doing so with the library "time" and to count seconds while running the functions for a large number of "n".

Does anyone have a better idea? maybe it already exists? :)

Thanks!
Amihay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfectly reasonable approach, for the time complexity at least. Make sure that your program outputs in a useful format, for example CSV or tab separated, so that you can easily copy/load this into a spreadsheet.

Space complexity might be a bit more tricky to get reliably. For this, you might want to modify your functions so that they return a useful metric. For example, if the main data structure of your algorithm is a map of fixed elements, then returning the maximum size of the map during the run would give you enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Write some tests and do performance profiling. Of course, you can write your own functions, but that is not the way how it is done. Good profiler will provide you with all kinds of information you can imagine.

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) tutorial on msnd about profiling.